# How to properly setup Socket.io on React/Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have Express/React app and now I am using Socket.io

Server is on :5000 port and client is on :3000 port.

Here is my Socket setup:

**server.js**

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server)
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User connected')

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected')
    })
})

app.io = io;
```

**Router.js**

```
if (data.length === 0) {
  req.app.io.emit("userID", {});
  return false;
}
```

**package.json** :

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

And front-end part :

**App.js** :

```
  state = {
    endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
    userError: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
    socket.on("userID", (data) => {
    });
  }
```

Am I doing it right? I was wondering to put my app on the Heroku and I don't think it will work, because I won't have same *endpoint*.

How may I enhance my code?

Thanks!